# SPServices GetListItems lookup field not retrieved

Tags: moss, spservices

With a MOSS 2007 Custom List 
having a field that is a lookup type into another Custom List at the same site, 
using the following fails to bring in the lookup field, 
though the other (non-lookup) fields *are* present in the results

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" 
              + " <FieldRef Name='Title' />  " 
              + " <FieldRef Name='Dt_x0020_Sec_x0020_Lev' />" 
              + "</ViewFields> ",
      listName: "Media Inventory",
      completefunc: Get_MI_Completed
    });
```

The Single Line of Text fields, Date/Time fields, etc. are present in the response, 
but not the Lookup field which is a single line of text.

The list referenced in GetListItems has 285 entries, 
the looked-up value comes from a list with 126 entries.

Answer (score 0):

Do any of the rows in the table that contains the lookup field (the one with 285 entries) have a value set on that field? or is it blank?
In my experience, Sharepoint will not return a column (Field) if it is not set (very annoying).  You can test this by narrowing your GetListItems to a single list row and then play with setting and clearing the Lookup Field